# Jenkins on debian server, can't install gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, debian, gradle, build-server

I am installing Jenkins for my gradle based android builds.

My server is running Debian 6.0 but gradle on that platform is currently in "unstable / testing" phase. This is not surprising given how much I had to wrestle with it with android studio, it didn't seem ready, but this is conjecture.

I got my gradle package from here http://packages.debian.org/sid/gradle but after unzipping the tar I was confronted with some files and I couldn't find the file that would let me install it from the terminal. the bootstrap.sh file produces many errors... not sure I am going down the right path here

insight appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just using the Jenkins [Gradle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin).

You configure your gradle installations in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System`

You have 2 options for configuring your gradle installs for jenkins:

1. Choose "Install automatically" option - this will download whatever version of gradle you specify from Gradle.org into your $JENKINS_HOME/tools directory - **this is the easiest option**
2. Set the GRADLE_HOME field to point to an existing Gradle install - you can just download a [binaries-only distribution](http://www.gradle.org/downloads) of gradle and unzip it somewhere

In your job, jenkins will execute gradle using the full path like `$JENKINS_HOME/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_1.8/bin/gradle`, so you don't need to worry about the gradle executable being on your `PATH` or in `/usr/bin` or anything like that.

I don't think you really need to mess w/ a Debian package if you just want to use gradle within Jenkins.

Hope that helps! :)